# How do I connect to Remix in Mist or MetaMask?

Tags: mist, json-rpc, mix, metamask, remix

If I use either Mist or MetaMask, I get the error message:

> Unable to connect to http://localhost:8545. Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

How can I connect to the Remix localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're waiting for the Remix team to add support. Currently they only support local nodes running, but marked the issue as "soon" on October 4th:

https://github.com/ethereum/remix/issues/105

Answer (score -1):

I haven't actually used Mix, the Dapp IDE myself, but based on [their documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mix:-The-DApp-IDE), and that error, it looks like it requires a local node running, and does not take advantage of an injected web3 API, the way Mist and MetaMask provide.

Comment: I am running a local geth node with Mist :/

Comment: I'm not sure Mist actually exposes its local geth node's port. MIX definitely requires a server on port 8545.

Comment: You are confusing Mix with Remix. Mix was discontinued in favor of Remix.